# How can I get an direct Instagram link from a twitter entity?

Tags: php, javascript, instagram

I have a twitter feed and I can find the instagram url in a tweet.

```
{
    indices: [
        90,
        110
    ],
    url: "http://t.co/kF9EXifn",
    expanded_url: "http://instagr.am/p/QC8hWKL_4K/",
    display_url: "instagr.am/p/QC8hWKL_4K/"
}
```

What I need is to take the expanded url from that object "http://instagr.am/p/QC8hWKL_4K/" and get the link to *just* the image itself, not the image on the Instagram site.  Anyone know how to do that?  Can I even derive the that link from the url?

Comment: You could probably get it by using the Instagram API: http://instagram.com/developer/

Comment: Checkout this part of the API, http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/ 

Expand the sample response and look for the `image` property

Comment: Using the Instagram api would require another (unspecified) amount of service calls.  I'm hoping to derive the url to the image from the url I'm provided.

Comment: Also I only need the image itself, no meta data.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can get just the image by appending `/media/` to the URL. Using your example: http://instagr.am/p/QC8hWKL_4K/media/.

You can even specify a size,

> One of t (thumbnail), m (medium), l (large). Defaults to m.

So for a thumbnail: http://instagr.am/p/QC8hWKL_4K/media/?size=t

Documentation [here](http://instagram.com/developer/embedding/).

Comment: you're awesome :) greetings from austria.