# Where do I find the Instagram media ID of a image

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm am looking for the `MediaID` of an Instagram image which has been uploaded. It should look like

> 1234567894561231236_33215652

I have found out the last set of integers are the `usersID`

For example: this is the link for the image directly, however I see no `mediaID` in the correct format?

```
http://distilleryimage11.ak.instagram.com/d33aafc8b55d11e2a66b22000a9f09de_7.jpg
```

while this is the link

```
http://instagram.com/p/Y7GF-5vftL/
```

I don't wish to use the API as all I need the MediaID from a selected image.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

## Here's a better way:

```
http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagram.com/p/Y7GF-5vftL/
```

Render as json object and you can easily extract media id from it ---

**For instance, in PHP**

```
$api = file_get_contents("http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagram.com/p/Y7‌​GF-5vftL/");      
$apiObj = json_decode($api,true);      
$media_id = $apiObj['media_id'];
```

**For instance, in JS**

```
$.ajax({     
    type: 'GET',     
    url: 'http://api.instagram.com/oembed?callback=&url=http://instagram.com/p/Y7GF-5vftL‌​/',     
    cache: false,     
    dataType: 'jsonp',     
    success: function(data) {           
        try{              
            var media_id = data[0].media_id;          
        }catch(err){}   
    } 
});
```

Comment: `$api = file_get_contents("http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagram.com/p/Y7GF-5vftL/");

    $apiObj = json_decode($api,true);

    $media_id = $apiObj['media_id'];`

Comment: Thanks for reply i was referring to javascrip method without php ! Is it possible without php ? Or there will be cross domain restriction with ajax call?

Comment: I have not tested this, but off the top of my head:

`$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.instagram.com/oembed?callback=&url=http://instagram.com/p/Y7GF-5vftL/',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) { 
         try{
             var media_id = data[0].media_id;
         }catch(e){
   
         }
 }
});`

If you need further help, create a new ticket and let me know

Comment: many thanks i had to use  var media_id = data.media_id instead. you think i can jsonp all instagram api this way? it is good way because it takes away load on the server using jsonp.

Comment: yes and no. there isn't a limit to the number of api calls for this particular api. But for the rest of instagram's api, there is a 5000 request/hour limit per client_id and 30 request/hour limit on access token. depending on which you need.

Comment: why oembed fails on private profiles? I want get image media id of private profiles that i am following already but using above method fails! Is yhere any other way to get those media ids for private profiles?

Comment: you will need access, using instagram API and permission from the users. [respective link](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

Comment: I am already following the user so its means i have permission but the above api link return nothing!for all private profiles the above api url fails! Do i need to pass it my access token?how?

Comment: The user needs to give your app the permission - following is not enough. Do create a separate question, and state what you've tried and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 24):

So the most up-voted *"Better Way"* is a little deprecated so here is my edit and other solutions:

**Javascript + jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.instagram.com/oembed?callback=&url='+Url, //You must define 'Url' for yourself
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    jsonp: false,
    success: function (data) {
       var MediaID = data.media_id;
   }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$your_url = "" //Input your url
$api = file_get_contents("http://api.instagram.com/oembed?callback=&url=" . your_url);      
$media_id = json_decode($api,true)['media_id'];
```

So, this is just an updated version of @George's code and is currently working. However, I made other solutions, and some even avoid an ajax request:

---

**Shortcode Ajax Solution**

Certain Instagram urls use a shortened url syntax. This allows the client to just use the shortcode in place of the media id if requested properly.

An example shortcode url looks like this: `https://www.instagram.com/p/Y7GF-5vftL/`

The `Y7GF-5vftL` is your shortcode for the picture.

*Using Regexp:*

```
var url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/Y7GF-5vftL/"; //Define this yourself
var Key = /p\/(.*?)\/$/.exec(url)[1];
```

In the same scope, `Key` will contain your shortcode. Now to request, let's say, a low res picture using this shortcode, you would do something like the following:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/shortcode/" + Key + "?access_token=" + access_token, //Define your 'access_token'
        success: function (RawData) {
            var LowResURL = RawData.data.images.low_resolution.url;
        }
    });
```

*There is lots of other useful information, including the media id, in the returned RawData structure. Log it or look up the api documentation to see.*

---

**Shortcode Conversion Solution**

You can actually convert your shortcode to the id fairly easily! Here's a simple way to do it in javascript:

```
function shortcodeToInstaID(Shortcode) {
      var char;
      var id = 0;
      var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_';
      for (var i = 0; i < Shortcode.length; i++) {
          char = Shortcode[i];
          id = (id * 64) + alphabet.indexOf(char);
      }
      return id;
  }
```

*Note: If you want a more robust node.js solution, or want to see how you would convert it back, check out @Slang's [module on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-id-to-url-segment).*

---

**Full Page Solution**

So what if you have the URL to a full Instagram page like: https://www.instagram.com/p/BAYYJBwi0Tssh605CJP2bmSuRpm_Jt7V_S8q9A0/

Well, you can actually read the HTML to find a meta property that contains the Media ID. There are also a couple other algorithms you can perform on the URL itself to get it, but I believe that requires too much effort so we will keep it simple. Either [query the meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524585/how-do-i-get-the-information-from-a-meta-tag-with-javascript) `al:ios:url` or iterate through the html. Since reading metatags is posted all over, I'll show you how to iterate.

*NOTE: This is a little unstable and is vulnerable to being patched. This method does NOT work on a page that uses a preview box. So if you give it the current HTML when you click on a picture in someone's profile, this WILL break and return a bad Media ID.*

```
function getMediaId(HTML_String) {
  var MediaID = "";
  var e = HTML_String.indexOf("al:ios:url") + 42; //HTML_String is a variable that contains all of the HTML text as a string for the current document. There are many different ways to retrieve this so look one up. 
  for (var i = e; i <= e + 100; i++) { //100 should never come close to being reached
      if (request.source.charAt(i) == "\"")
         break;
      MediaID += request.source.charAt(i);
  }
  return MediaID;
}
```

---

And there you go, a bunch of different ways to use Instagram's api to get a Media ID. Hope one fixes your struggles.

Answer (score 23):

## Here's an *even* better way:

No API calls!  And I threw in converting a `media_id` to a `shortcode` as an added bonus.

Based on [slang's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/915948/slang) [amazing work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31714162/345599) for figuring out the conversion.  [Nathan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379504/nathan) [work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3200170/345599) converting base10 to base64 in php.  And [rgbflawed's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947374/rgbflawed) [work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32020520/345599) converting it back the other way (with a modified alphabet). #teameffort

```
function mediaid_to_shortcode($mediaid){

    if(strpos($mediaid, '_') !== false){
        $pieces = explode('_', $mediaid);
        $mediaid = $pieces[0];
        $userid = $pieces[1];
    }

    $alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_';
    $shortcode = '';
    while($mediaid > 0){
        $remainder = $mediaid % 64;
        $mediaid = ($mediaid-$remainder) / 64;
        $shortcode = $alphabet{$remainder} . $shortcode;
    };

    return $shortcode;

}

function shortcode_to_mediaid($shortcode){

    $alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_';

    $mediaid = 0;

    foreach(str_split($shortcode) as $letter) {
        $mediaid = ($mediaid*64) + strpos($alphabet, $letter);
    }

    return $mediaid;

}
```

Comment: Not working for me anymore. I guess is deprecated.

Answer (score 16):

## Here's a *much* better way (No Instagram API):

1. Get the permalink URL of the Instagram image you need the media ID for. 
   `http://instagram.com/p/Y7GF-5vftL/`
2. add **`?__a=1`** at the end of the permalink
   `http://instagram.com/p/Y7GF-5vftL/?__a=1`

[Run the link in a browser](http://instagram.com/p/Y7GF-5vftL/?__a=1) and Instagram will provide all the metadata of the image in JSON, from which you can easily recover the image ID and other valuable data.

The JSON response will look like this:

```
{
  "graphql": {
    "shortcode_media": {
      "__typename": "GraphImage",
      "id": "448979387270691659",
      "shortcode": "Y7GF-5vftL",
      "dimensions": {
        "height": 612,
        "width": 612
      },
      "gating_info": null,
      "fact_check_overall_rating": null,
      "fact_check_information": null,
      "sensitivity_friction_info": null,
      "sharing_friction_info": {
        "should_have_sharing_friction": false,
        "bloks_app_url": null
      },
      "media_overlay_info": null,
      "media_preview": null,
      "display_url": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e15/11324452_400723196800905_116356150_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=YQtotj4Ygh0AX9Vqa8s&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=9f8658a873a3e94a462db148bde85b5a&oe=61A49EE6&_nc_sid=83d603",
      "display_resources": [
        {
          "src": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e15/11324452_400723196800905_116356150_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=YQtotj4Ygh0AX9Vqa8s&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=9f8658a873a3e94a462db148bde85b5a&oe=61A49EE6&_nc_sid=83d603",
          "config_width": 640,
          "config_height": 640
        },
        {
          "src": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e15/11324452_400723196800905_116356150_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=YQtotj4Ygh0AX9Vqa8s&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=9f8658a873a3e94a462db148bde85b5a&oe=61A49EE6&_nc_sid=83d603",
          "config_width": 750,
          "config_height": 750
        },
        {
          "src": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e15/11324452_400723196800905_116356150_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=YQtotj4Ygh0AX9Vqa8s&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=9f8658a873a3e94a462db148bde85b5a&oe=61A49EE6&_nc_sid=83d603",
          "config_width": 1080,
          "config_height": 1080
        }
      ],
      "accessibility_caption": "Photo by Steven Caelius Thirlwall on May 05, 2013.",
      "is_video": false,
      "tracking_token": "eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjpmYWxzZSwidXVpZCI6IjFjOTliZDQ5MTU0YzQ2ODY4OGY5MmM4ODgwYWQ4NGQzNDQ4OTc5Mzg3MjcwNjkxNjU5Iiwic2VydmVyX3Rva2VuIjoiMTYzNzY4NDc1NjI4MHw0NDg5NzkzODcyNzA2OTE2NTl8MzExMTA2NDAyfDE2ZGMyNjk3M2M1YWY5YWEzOTNhZTY5YzEzYzU4YjM5NWI0YWQ3MjY1OGQxOTg4YWQ2OWUxYmI3ZjkyNzU5ZDQifSwic2lnbmF0dXJlIjoiIn0=",
      "upcoming_event": null,
      "edge_media_to_tagged_user": {
        "edges": []
      },
      "edge_media_to_caption": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "text": "New ankle biter! #Beagle #pup #shoes #blueisthecolor #cute #iwantone"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "can_see_insights_as_brand": false,
      "caption_is_edited": false,
      "has_ranked_comments": false,
      "like_and_view_counts_disabled": false,
      "edge_media_to_parent_comment": {
        "count": 902,
        "page_info": {
          "has_next_page": true,
          "end_cursor": "QVFBZFlTbmNsVWh1T2dIS1I3Mm8yRl9DdGVQMHV6VXg5cjQxZzlYa0gxQ1NFZGc5a1FfWHhIMTlURU84dlBCcG5QX1I2VXhvVXNpbGRGWlktNG5FTjdRTQ=="
        },
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "17916614443887715",
              "text": "@h___ep10",
              "created_at": 1632633242,
              "did_report_as_spam": false,
              "owner": {
                "id": "7472159900",
                "is_verified": false,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/33736445_386998071786552_2814599361646821376_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=kaD1UHiVnU8AX9oWv0I&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=cabcfaac8d48b63b41f0e9a32bb0282f&oe=61A38CDE&_nc_sid=83d603",
                "username": "x._raha.moradi_.x"
              },
              "viewer_has_liked": false,
              "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 0
              },
              "is_restricted_pending": false,
              "edge_threaded_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                  "has_next_page": false,
                  "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "17894221358363984",
              "text": "@zahraroshanikia",
              "created_at": 1632633244,
              "did_report_as_spam": false,
              "owner": {
                "id": "46440556914",
                "is_verified": false,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/159256912_431734447917250_5641996282890612011_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=110&_nc_ohc=y2JgjQ2mc6EAX8U9OnZ&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=95911a34aea9f1fe0f6ae941154de86b&oe=61A4F7B5&_nc_sid=83d603",
                "username": "saman.wx68"
              },
              "viewer_has_liked": false,
              "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 0
              },
              "is_restricted_pending": false,
              "edge_threaded_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                  "has_next_page": false,
                  "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "17931125308699029",
              "text": "@azarimani55",
              "created_at": 1632633244,
              "did_report_as_spam": false,
              "owner": {
                "id": "33210479560",
                "is_verified": false,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/94635563_230560861379228_5419754827787796480_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=7JyeFrDCzcMAX_uDrhk&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=5599a78e5508ca3827b5c580c4e5daf0&oe=61A3CB8E&_nc_sid=83d603",
                "username": "alirezaekhteraee"
              },
              "viewer_has_liked": false,
              "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 0
              },
              "is_restricted_pending": false,
              "edge_threaded_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                  "has_next_page": false,
                  "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "18164016367163647",
              "text": "@mbahrambagi436",
              "created_at": 1632633245,
              "did_report_as_spam": false,
              "owner": {
                "id": "45915987079",
                "is_verified": false,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/148716764_428606351708713_8819828798031017255_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=ZKBGqc8f6xAAX_roxPf&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=0b8ed79236bf5e97dde3a4621a1cc647&oe=61A3B2BD&_nc_sid=83d603",
                "username": "xx77llxxrdd"
              },
              "viewer_has_liked": false,
              "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 0
              },
              "is_restricted_pending": false,
              "edge_threaded_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                  "has_next_page": false,
                  "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "17921916424799580",
              "text": "@soheila.rezvan",
              "created_at": 1632633246,
              "did_report_as_spam": false,
              "owner": {
                "id": "47289012029",
                "is_verified": false,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/44884218_345707102882519_2446069589734326272_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=uQzgj27XaGsAX_EK6es&edm=AA0lj5EBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=11aea858038a83aea909c6a5934ac670&oe=61A4378F&_nc_sid=3add00&ig_cache_key=YW5vbnltb3VzX3Byb2ZpbGVfcGlj.2-ccb7-4",
                "username": "ha_midreza2843"
              },
              "viewer_has_liked": false,
              "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 0
              },
              "is_restricted_pending": false,
              "edge_threaded_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                  "has_next_page": false,
                  "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "17907564257125873",
              "text": "@paria_niazi80",
              "created_at": 1632633247,
              "did_report_as_spam": false,
              "owner": {
                "id": "46492412778",
                "is_verified": false,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/260070060_924734438469169_5591668570031114480_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=fl-bN9uNz9sAX_v_XtR&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=a875da2937ac853d3111499bc32fa452&oe=61A43C46&_nc_sid=83d603",
                "username": "ricky_gutierrezz4"
              },
              "viewer_has_liked": false,
              "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 0
              },
              "is_restricted_pending": false,
              "edge_threaded_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                  "has_next_page": false,
                  "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "17922561976794017",
              "text": "@memmm.mom",
              "created_at": 1632633247,
              "did_report_as_spam": false,
              "owner": {
                "id": "47086299475",
                "is_verified": false,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/44884218_345707102882519_2446069589734326272_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=uQzgj27XaGsAX_EK6es&edm=AA0lj5EBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=11aea858038a83aea909c6a5934ac670&oe=61A4378F&_nc_sid=3add00&ig_cache_key=YW5vbnltb3VzX3Byb2ZpbGVfcGlj.2-ccb7-4",
                "username": "izadiizadi2"
              },
              "viewer_has_liked": false,
              "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 0
              },
              "is_restricted_pending": false,
              "edge_threaded_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                  "has_next_page": false,
                  "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "18130172461216294",
              "text": "@221bcc",
              "created_at": 1632633247,
              "did_report_as_spam": false,
              "owner": {
                "id": "47371753534",
                "is_verified": false,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/44884218_345707102882519_2446069589734326272_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=uQzgj27XaGsAX_EK6es&edm=AA0lj5EBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=11aea858038a83aea909c6a5934ac670&oe=61A4378F&_nc_sid=3add00&ig_cache_key=YW5vbnltb3VzX3Byb2ZpbGVfcGlj.2-ccb7-4",
                "username": "karimov_94422"
              },
              "viewer_has_liked": false,
              "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 0
              },
              "is_restricted_pending": false,
              "edge_threaded_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                  "has_next_page": false,
                  "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "17932389193640009",
              "text": "@tehran___la",
              "created_at": 1632633248,
              "did_report_as_spam": false,
              "owner": {
                "id": "46622156073",
                "is_verified": false,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/44884218_345707102882519_2446069589734326272_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=uQzgj27XaGsAX_EK6es&edm=AA0lj5EBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=11aea858038a83aea909c6a5934ac670&oe=61A4378F&_nc_sid=3add00&ig_cache_key=YW5vbnltb3VzX3Byb2ZpbGVfcGlj.2-ccb7-4",
                "username": "rynwrynw627"
              },
              "viewer_has_liked": false,
              "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 0
              },
              "is_restricted_pending": false,
              "edge_threaded_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                  "has_next_page": false,
                  "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "17935588228640366",
              "text": "@sepideh.m.i.r",
              "created_at": 1632633248,
              "did_report_as_spam": false,
              "owner": {
                "id": "5905800882",
                "is_verified": false,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/160110991_451499282792610_787693123774809640_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=CBgOU0M1MPYAX8m7vvT&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=18a215ed2c3a0cd0e58a905e22cd0c8f&oe=61A489B4&_nc_sid=83d603",
                "username": "__mohammad__677"
              },
              "viewer_has_liked": false,
              "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 0
              },
              "is_restricted_pending": false,
              "edge_threaded_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                  "has_next_page": false,
                  "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "17854564814634983",
              "text": "@nilooofar5828",
              "created_at": 1632633249,
              "did_report_as_spam": false,
              "owner": {
                "id": "46091925856",
                "is_verified": false,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/44884218_345707102882519_2446069589734326272_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=uQzgj27XaGsAX_EK6es&edm=AA0lj5EBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=11aea858038a83aea909c6a5934ac670&oe=61A4378F&_nc_sid=3add00&ig_cache_key=YW5vbnltb3VzX3Byb2ZpbGVfcGlj.2-ccb7-4",
                "username": "hsheh6154"
              },
              "viewer_has_liked": false,
              "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 0
              },
              "is_restricted_pending": false,
              "edge_threaded_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                  "has_next_page": false,
                  "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "17907793715125698",
              "text": "@oran31201816",
              "created_at": 1632633249,
              "did_report_as_spam": false,
              "owner": {
                "id": "44672434922",
                "is_verified": false,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/149881733_183016319827876_8572211010018355650_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=JgjvztBQGrIAX8nLUiM&tn=hRpIRP1GgMkkZ4n7&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=d9e408cf78f195a83f8bb7beec8c22c1&oe=61A360EC&_nc_sid=83d603",
                "username": "barcelona10_trol"
              },
              "viewer_has_liked": false,
              "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 0
              },
              "is_restricted_pending": false,
              "edge_threaded_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                  "has_next_page": false,
                  "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "edge_media_to_hoisted_comment": {
        "edges": []
      },
      "edge_media_preview_comment": {
        "count": 902,
        "edges": []
      },
      "comments_disabled": false,
      "commenting_disabled_for_viewer": false,
      "taken_at_timestamp": 1367742535,
      "edge_media_preview_like": {
        "count": 13823,
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "750983393",
              "is_verified": false,
              "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/245113529_402184758053910_6991076024439577169_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=TPs3jHagdx4AX_JdrO5&tn=hRpIRP1GgMkkZ4n7&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=95f6532e2d737a91e3848fa0525319e4&oe=61A4C0D1&_nc_sid=83d603",
              "username": "josepkoray"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "edge_media_to_sponsor_user": {
        "edges": []
      },
      "is_affiliate": false,
      "is_paid_partnership": false,
      "location": null,
      "viewer_has_liked": false,
      "viewer_has_saved": false,
      "viewer_has_saved_to_collection": false,
      "viewer_in_photo_of_you": false,
      "viewer_can_reshare": true,
      "owner": {
        "id": "45818965",
        "is_verified": false,
        "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/38792937_2121773964703196_2247098649857228800_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=LyE1N2PfQ3IAX9R25jq&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=29912db673500a2adc9df6ec7241d8c7&oe=61A471D2&_nc_sid=83d603",
        "username": "taz4535",
        "blocked_by_viewer": false,
        "restricted_by_viewer": false,
        "followed_by_viewer": false,
        "full_name": "Steven Caelius Thirlwall",
        "has_blocked_viewer": false,
        "is_embeds_disabled": false,
        "is_private": false,
        "is_unpublished": false,
        "requested_by_viewer": false,
        "pass_tiering_recommendation": false,
        "edge_owner_to_timeline_media": {
          "count": 236
        },
        "edge_followed_by": {
          "count": 700
        }
      },
      "is_ad": false,
      "edge_web_media_to_related_media": {
        "edges": []
      },
      "coauthor_producers": [],
      "edge_related_profiles": {
        "edges": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use the same **`?__a=1`** ending even on Instagram *user permalinks*, for example `https://www.instagram.com/taz4535/?__a=1`  and you'll get incredibly valuable user data in the [reply JSON](https://www.instagram.com/taz4535/?__a=1).

The best is that this is **all done without Instagram API authentication!**

Comment: Info: The Media Id is a string containing two ids. First the real post id, which is the id in the output above and the account id of the account who posted it. The account id is at graphql -> owner -> id.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: no more working.

Comment: as yild mentioned, Instagram discontinued this unofficial ?__a=1 api endpoint

Answer (score 14):

You can actually derive the MediaId from the last segment of the link algorithmically using a method I wrote about here: http://carrot.is/coding/instagram-ids. It works by mapping the URL segment by character codes & converting the id into a base 64 number.

For example, given the link you mentioned (http://instagram.com/p/Y7GF-5vftL), we get the last segment (`Y7GF-5vftL`) then we map it into character codes using the [base64 url-safe alphabet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5) (`24:59:6:5:62:57:47:31:45:11_64`). Next, we convert this base64 number into base10 (`448979387270691659`).

If you append your userId after an `_` you get the full id in the form you specified, but since the MediaId is unique without the userId you can actually omit the userId from most requests.

Finally, I made a Node.js module called [instagram-id-to-url-segment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-id-to-url-segment) to automate this conversion:

```
convert = require('instagram-id-to-url-segment');
instagramIdToUrlSegment = convert.instagramIdToUrlSegment;
urlSegmentToInstagramId = convert.urlSegmentToInstagramId;

instagramIdToUrlSegment('448979387270691659'); // Y7GF-5vftL
urlSegmentToInstagramId('Y7GF-5vftL'); // 448979387270691659
```

Answer (score 8):

Try the solution from this question:
[How can I get an direct Instagram link from a twitter entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682039/how-can-i-get-an-direct-instagram-link-from-a-twitter-entity)

> You can get just the image by appending /media/ to the URL. Using your
>
> > You can even specify a size,
>
> One of t (thumbnail), m (medium), l (large). Defaults to m.
>
> So for a thumbnail: http://instagr.am/p/QC8hWKL_4K/media/?size=t

Comment: @pal4life Try using one media existing. Worked for me with another image: http://instagram.com/p/xrXtpsqlaV/media?size=l

Answer (score 8):

Here is python solution to do this without api call.

```
def media_id_to_code(media_id):
    alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_'
    short_code = ''
    while media_id > 0:
        remainder = media_id % 64
        media_id = (media_id-remainder)/64
        short_code = alphabet[remainder] + short_code
    return short_code


def code_to_media_id(short_code):
    alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_'
    media_id = 0;
    for letter in short_code:
        media_id = (media_id*64) + alphabet.index(letter)

    return media_id
```

Comment: NOTE: for python3 you should use "//64" instead of "/64" because of division operator behavior change, see "floor division" for details.

Comment: There is method in instabot-py library bot.get_media_id_from_link("https://www.instagram.com/p/BAYYJBwi0Ts/"). The result is the same as code_to_media_id ("BAYYJBwi0Ts").

Comment: `media_id, remainder = divmod(media_id, 64)`

Answer (score 3):

Your media ID is: `448979387270691659_45818965`
This is how to get it.

1. Go to instgram.com/username.
2. Click the photo you want the id of.
3. (Chrome instructions) right click on the photo (should be a popup image)
4. Inspect element
5. Search through the selected text, you should see something like this `photo448979387270691659_45818965`

There should be your photo ID.

For some reason, this only seems to work with the popup, and not the actual image URL.

Answer (score 3):

In pure JS (provided your browser can handle XHRs, which every major browser [including IE > 6] can):

```
function igurlretrieve(url) {

  var urldsrc = "http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=" + url;

  //fetch data from URL data source
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open('GET', urldsrc, true);
  x.send();

  //load resulting JSON data as JS object
  var urldata = JSON.parse(x.responseText);

  //reconstruct data as "instagram://" URL that can be opened in iOS app
  var reconsturl = "instagram://media?id=" + urldata.media_id;
  return reconsturl;

}
```

Provided this is your goal -- simply opening the page in the Instagram iOS app, which is exactly what this is about -- this should do, especially if you don't want to have to endure licensing fees.

Answer (score 2):

**edit**

The iOS Instagram app has now registered for regular http links to open in the Instagram app and this deeplink methodology is no longer necessary.

**old**

Swift 4 short-code parsing solution

```
private static func instagramDeepLinkFromHTTPLink(_ link: String) -> String? {
    guard let shortcode = link.components(separatedBy: "/").last else { return nil }

    // algorithm from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246231/337934
    let alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_"
    var mediaId: Int = 0
    for (_, char) in shortcode.enumerated() {
        guard let index = alphabet.index(of: char) else { continue }
        mediaId = (mediaId * 64) + index.encodedOffset
    }

    return "instagram://media?id=\(mediaId)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same thing you can implement in Python-

```
import requests,json

def get_media_id(media_url):
   url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?callback=&url=' + media_url
   response = requests.get(url).json()
   print(response['media_id'])

get_media_id('MEDIA_URL')
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Instagram media id to Shortcode
> 2. Instagram Shortcode to media id

```
var bigint = require( 'big-integer' )

var lower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var upper = lower.toUpperCase();
var numbers = '0123456789'
var ig_alphabet =  upper + lower + numbers + '-_'
var bigint_alphabet = numbers + lower

function toShortcode( longid ){

    var o = bigint( longid ).toString( 64 )
    return o.replace(/<(\d+)>|(\w)/g, (m,m1,m2) =>{
    return ig_alphabet.charAt( ( m1 )
      ? parseInt( m1 ) 
      : bigint_alphabet.indexOf( m2 ) )
    });
}

function fromShortcode( shortcode ){
    var o = shortcode.replace( /\S/g, m =>{
    var c = ig_alphabet.indexOf( m )
    var b = bigint_alphabet.charAt( c ) 
    return ( b != "" ) ? b : `<${c}>`
    })  
    return bigint( o, 64 ).toString( 10 )
}

toShortcode(  '908540701891980503' ) // s.b. 'ybyPRoQWzX'
fromShortcode( 'ybyPRoQWzX' ) // s.b. '908540701891980503'
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation - what this does?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shortcode media API from instagram. If you use php you can use the following code to get the shortcode from the image's URL:

```
$matches = [];

preg_match('/instagram\.com\/p\/([^\/]*)/i', $url, $matches);

if (count($matches) > 1) {
    $shortcode = $matches[1];
}
```

Then send a request to the API using your access token (Replace `ACCESS-TOKEN` with your token)

```
$apiUrl = sprintf("https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/shortcode/%s?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN", $shortcode);
```

Comment: This isn't working. Throwing an error, "Page Not Found &bull; Instagram"

Comment: This is actually deprecated. Instagram's API is not active anymore ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Instagram deprecated their legacy APIs in support for [Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) during the late 2019

In **Basic Display API** you are supposed to use the  following API endpoint to get the *media id*. You will need to supply a valid *access token*.

```
https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption&access_token={access-token}
```

You can read here on how to configure test account and generate **access token** on [Facebook developer portal](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview#instagram-user-access-tokens).

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started) is another article which also describes about how to get access token.

Answer (score 0):

## instaloader method

You can do it with [instaloader](https://instaloader.github.io/) python module too.

First install it with a command like this:

```
pip3 install instaloader
```

then you can get media id from a shortcode like this:

```py
import instaloader
from instaloader import *

L = instaloader.Instaloader()
post_shortcode = "Y7GF-5vftL" # or whatever code it is
media_id = Post.shortcode_to_mediaid(post_shortcode)
print(media_id)
```

for more information you can refer to [here](https://instaloader.github.io/module/structures.html?highlight=shortcode#instaloader.Post.shortcode_to_mediaid)

Answer (score -1):

Right click on a photo and open in a new tab/window. Right click on `inspect element`. Search for:

> instagram://media?id=

This will give you:

> instagram://media?id=############# ***/// the ID***

The full id construct from

`photoID_userID`

To get the user id, search for:

> instapp:owner_user_id ***Will be in content=***